# Ubuntu 12.04 virtual host domain enabled, but does not get loaded

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

This is my first attempt at setting up virtual hosts in Apache. I am trying to set up the subdomain `test.mysite.com` for `mysite.com`.

My VPS had Apache already installed on it. In `/var/www`there was an `index.html` file live and running. What I have done since is:

1. Created `/var/www/main/` which is now the default document root,
2. Created `/var/www/test/` which is the content to be served by my virtual host,
3. Copied `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` to `etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.com`.
4. Run `a2ensite test.mysite.com` with a successful message that the site is enabled,
5. Run `service apache2 reload` to reload the server.

These are the first lines that I have modified in `etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ...
```

According to all the guides and tutorials I have found, the subdomain should now be up and running. But my browser can't find the page. Is there anything else I need to do to get my subsite up and running?

**EDIT: SOLVED**
The answer had nothing to do with the apache configuration files. I just had to register the subdomain at my hosting provider. I will mark this as the answer when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer had nothing to do with the apache configuration files. I just had to register the subdomain at my hosting provider.